# Horizontal database scaling in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

I have a Ruby on Rails app with a PostgreSQL database which has this structure:

```
class A < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :B
end
class B < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :C
end
class C < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :x, :y :z
end
```

The are only a few A's, and they grow slowly (say 5 a month). Each A has thousands of B's, and each B has tens of thousands of C's (so each A has millions of C's).

A's are independent and B's and C's from different A's will never be needed together (i.e. in the same query).

My problem is that now that I have only a couple of A's, ActiveRecord queries take pretty long. When the table for C has tens of millions of rows, queries will take forever.

I am thinking about scaling the database horizontally (i.e a table for A's, one table of B's and one table of C's for each A). But I don't know how to do it. It is a kind of sharding i guess, but I can't figure out how to create DB tables dynamically and use ActiveRecord to access the data if the table depends on which A im working with.

Thank you very much.

Comment: If you do this, you might want to partition into different schemas so you don't make a kajillion tables in the `public` one.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know about schemas. How would I do that dynamically however?

Comment: If I were you I'd look for some kind of add-on or plugin that gives you a place to start. I'm not as familiar with the Postgres space, but there are things like [Octopus](https://github.com/tchandy/octopus) that might serve as a jumping off point.

Comment: You need to look at what SQL ends up being used, what indexes you have, and what EXPLAIN says about your SQL.

Comment: This seems like a good candidate question for http://dba.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have performance concerns with only a few rows, or even with several million rows, you need to take a step back before trying to atmosphere engineer a solution. The problem you are describing is very easily solved by indexing; there is no advantage to creating additional physical tables and you'd be introducing incredible complexity.

As @mu-is-too-short already stated: pay attention to your query plans. Use your tools to analyze performance.

That being said you can use [table partitioning](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/ddl-partitioning.html) to physically and transparently house the storage of data into different sharded tables which is especially useful for data that grows very fast but is only useful in a given time box (like a month). You can also do this with an archive bit flag column to shuttle old or deleted records onto some slower storage (say, standard RAID comprised of spinning rust) while keeping active records on faster storage (like a RAID of SSDs).

Comment: Thank you. What do you mean when you say the problem is solved by indexing? Currently C's have an index to link them to the B they belong to, and the same goes for B's with respect to their A.

Comment: If you have indexes on your tables even a few million rows should return relatively quickly, never "pretty long" unless you're using outdated hardware. As an experiment use a tool like Navicat to run the SQL statement you think is executed by ActiveRecord - its often not what you think - and see how that compares with AR's performance. Tail your log/development.log and see if you're falling prey to N+1 query performance (by inadvertently excluding a join). I'm curious to know what sort of in-process requirement needs millions of rows to operate on; MM+ row operations are normally out of proc.

Answer (score 0):

So it seems you have a tree-like structure. If there is really no need to pull them out of the database in a some kind of cross-referenced manner, then your A's have exactly the properties of a "document", have a look at MongoDB. A's would be saved with all of their B's and there C's in a single record.

http://www.mongodb.org/

If you are looking for an ORM, check

http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/index.html

Comment: Thank you! I hadn't thought about NoSQL, maybe that's what I'm looking for

Comment: There are write-performance concerns to properly plan out if you use Mongo, though since 2.2 the global lock is gone (I haven't used it since 2.0) so perhaps its not as bad as it once was. You'll also need to consider redundancy - 10gen recommends six VMs (on different physical hosts) minimum for a scaled and redundant environment. Don't be afraid to denormalize your data - you have a good case to do so - before changing your underlying data storage. Additionally PostgreSQL has Hstore which is a NoSQL alternative, though that requires more research to see if its applicable.